# How to use subquery with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to create a subquery to bring two tables together but am getting nothing.

Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Agreements.AgrmntID, Agreements.Status, JobSites.SiteName,
  PurchaseOrderDetails.ExtCost
FROM Agreements Inner Join
  JobSites On Agreements.CustSiteID = JobSites.CustSiteID
WHERE Agreements.Status = 2 And PurchaseOrderDetails.ExtCost = (Select
    PurchaseOrderDetails.ExtCost
  FROM PurchaseOrderDetails 
  Inner Join PurchaseOrders On PurchaseOrders.POID = PurchaseOrderDetails.POID
  WHERE PurchaseOrders.Description Like ('%', JobSites.SiteName, '%') And   
  Convert(varchar(8),PurchaseOrderDetails.TimeCreated,1) = '09/10/12')
ORDER BY JobSites.SiteName
```

Expected Output:

```
AgreemntID   Status  SiteName  ExtCost
----------------------------------------
1            2       TEST01    $144.00
2            2       TEST02    $400.00
```

I'm using a subquery because there's nothing that links the ExtCost to the SiteName except the Description under PurchaseOrders.

Hopefully this is enough information for you to help me.  Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is just a typo when you wrote the question, but in your SQL you specify Agreements.Status = 2 but in your example you are expecting results with Status 3?

Otherwise, I would start by testing your individual subqueries to make sure your data is in the format you expect, eg try running

```
Select
    PurchaseOrderDetails.ExtCost
  FROM PurchaseOrderDetails 
  Inner Join PurchaseOrders On PurchaseOrders.POID = PurchaseOrderDetails.POID
  WHERE PurchaseOrders.Description Like ('%', JobSites.SiteName, '%') And   
  Convert(varchar(8),PurchaseOrderDetails.TimeCreated,1) = '09/10/12'
```

and see what you get back, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I think I understand what your trying to do you could use an outer apply like so

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.AgrmntID, A.Status, JobSites.SiteName,
  PurchaseOrderDetails.ExtCost
FROM Agreements A 
Join JobSites J On J.CustSiteID = A.CustSiteID
OUTER APPLY(Select P.ExtCost From 
PurchaseOrders PO
JOIN PurchaseOrderDetails POD ON POD.POID = PO.POID
Where PO.Description Like ('%', JobSites.SiteName, '%') And   
  Convert(varchar(8),PurchaseOrderDetails.TimeCreated,1) = '09/10/12') POD
WHERE A.Status = 2 AND POD.ExtCost IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY JobSites.SiteName
```